# Custom Lombok annotation method not showing up in Method view

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I've started to dabble with custom lombok transformations recently and have come up with a @HelloWorld transformation that simply prints out hello world. My unit test passes in checking and running the helloWorld method, however, when I go into the method view in intelliJ, it doesn't show up (unlike the getters and setters created by lombok). Can anyone check what I have and see what I'm missing? It would be appreciated!

FWIW: I'm doing the javac implementation.

```
@Override
public void handle(AnnotationValues<HelloWorld> annotation, JCAnnotation ast, JavacNode annotationNode) {

    handleFlagUsage(annotationNode, HELLO_WORLD_FLAG_USAGE, "@HelloWorld");

    JavacNode parent = annotationNode.up();
    validateType(parent, annotationNode);
    validateAccessLevel(annotation, annotationNode);
    validateParent(parent, annotationNode);

    JCMethodDecl helloWorld = createHelloWorld(annotationNode);
    JavacHandlerUtil.injectMethod(parent, helloWorld);
}

void validateType(JavacNode parent, JavacNode annotationNode) {
    JCClassDecl typeDecl = null;
    if (parent.get() instanceof JCClassDecl) typeDecl = (JCClassDecl) parent.get();
    long modifiers = typeDecl == null ? 0 : typeDecl.mods.flags;
    boolean notAClass = (modifiers & (Flags.INTERFACE | Flags.ANNOTATION | Flags.ENUM)) != 0;

    if (notAClass) {
        annotationNode.addError("@HelloWorld is only supported on a class");
    }
}

void validateAccessLevel(AnnotationValues<HelloWorld> annotation, JavacNode annotationNode) {
    HelloWorld annotationInstance = annotation.getInstance();
    AccessLevel level = annotationInstance.value();

    if (level == AccessLevel.NONE) {
        annotationNode.addError("No access level");
    }
}

void validateParent(JavacNode parent, JavacNode annotationNode) {
    if (parent == null) {
        annotationNode.addError("Parent is null");
    }
}

JCMethodDecl createHelloWorld(JavacNode node) {

    JavacTreeMaker treeMaker = node.getTreeMaker();

    // Generate method type
    JCExpression methodType = treeMaker.Type(Javac.createVoidType(treeMaker, CTC_VOID));
    // Generate the methodName
    Name methodName = node.toName("helloWorld");
    // Generate statements
    List<JCStatement> statements = createHelloWorldBody(treeMaker, node);
    // Generate method body
    JCBlock methodBody = treeMaker.Block(0, statements);
    // Generate generic types
    List<JCTypeParameter> methodGenericParams = List.nil();
    // Generate method parameters
    List<JCVariableDecl> parameters = List.nil();
    // Generate throws clause
    List<JCExpression> throwsClauses = List.nil();

    JCExpression annotationMethodDefaultValue = null;

    return treeMaker.MethodDef(
                    treeMaker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC),
                    methodName,
                    methodType,
                    methodGenericParams,
                    parameters,
                    throwsClauses,
                    methodBody,
                    annotationMethodDefaultValue);
}

List<JCStatement> createHelloWorldBody(JavacTreeMaker treeMaker, JavacNode field) {
    JCExpression printlnMethod = JavacHandlerUtil.chainDots(field, "System", "out", "println");
    List<JCExpression> printlnArgs = List.of(treeMaker.Literal("hello world"));
    return List.of(treeMaker.Exec(treeMaker.Apply(List.nil(), printlnMethod, printlnArgs)));
}
```

And here's my unit test showing a good run

[unit test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNNmD.png)

And here's the method view with getters and setters but without the helloWorld method.

[method view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZGhH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided above, you have touched only the JAVA compiler part of the Lombok plug-in. There are other parts of the lombok source code to make it smoothly integrate correctly with IDE-s, like intellyJ or Eclipse.

You are definitely want to continue the research at https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin.

The code when you are running using a JRE was generated by a JAVAC(gradle). That code is not used by the intellyJ IDE.

If you want to see the method in method view then you have to implement an **Annotation Processor** for intellyJ IDE.